# obtener en año a partir de una fecha contenida en un df

Tags: r

necesito filtrar solo el año en toda la columna que tiene la fecha completa dd-mm-yy en R.
Esto viene en un DF con tres campos. Fecha combustible clasificacion ambiental

Si me pueden ayudar agradecido, Saludos JVM

Comment: Bienvenido user154061 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Por favor, agrega una muestra de los datos, así como la salida de la función `str()` ya que no sabemoss de que tipo de dato estás hablando ¿es un `character`? ¿un `POSIXct`? etc.

Answer (score 1):

aqui una de las formas en que lo puede hacer

```
# para crear datos ejemplo 
set.seed(1984) 
fechas = (sample(seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2017-01-01'), by = "day"), 10)) 
fechas2 <- format(fechas, "%d-%m-%Y")
data = (cbind((sample(seq(1:100),10)), fechas2, format((fechas), "%Y"))) # se crea una columna que contiene solo años`
data
           fechas2            
 [1,] "89" "27-04-2016" "2016"
 [2,] "2"  "16-11-2015" "2015"
 [3,] "70" "30-09-2015" "2015"
 [4,] "98" "30-08-2015" "2015"
 [5,] "20" "20-06-2016" "2016"
 [6,] "3"  "19-09-2016" "2016"
 [7,] "29" "24-01-2015" "2015"
 [8,] "62" "21-11-2015" "2015"
 [9,] "85" "23-08-2016" "2016"
[10,] "19" "05-06-2015" "2015"
# fin de creacion de datos ejemplo

subset(data, data[,3] =="2015") # para filtrar por año 2015
          fechas2            
[1,] "2"  "16-11-2015" "2015"
[2,] "70" "30-09-2015" "2015"
[3,] "98" "30-08-2015" "2015"
[4,] "29" "24-01-2015" "2015"
[5,] "62" "21-11-2015" "2015"
[6,] "19" "05-06-2015" "2015"
```